# How can I use a count/quantity to add weight in Machine Learning?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Normally when I have done Machine Learning in the past I have essentially had one row for each observation.  In those cases, I just fed in my data line by line into the algorithm.  In my current data, I have what is essentially an index where one name has many counts to it.  My problem is in one year I could have a name associated to both Male and Female and I need to weight it by the count (I am building a gender classifier based on name).  I have included an image below as an example of how my data looks:

[image]

Maybe it is simple and I am missing it, but without expanding out the model into individual rows is there an easy way to read this into a machine learning algorithm and use the Count column to signify the weight?  I am primarily planning on using the SciKit Learn suite of tools.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply use pandas groupby function and have frequency of name+gender as a column. The below code you can refer to get started:

```
yourDataFrame = pd.DataFrame(colums=["Name","Gender","Age","SourceFile"])
yourDataFrame["Count"] = 1
dummyDf = yourDataFame.groupby(["Name","Gender"]).count("Count")
```

Now you can make a simple lookup function which combines yourDataFrame and dummydf for counts/weights.

Comment: Yes it will. I wrote it for better understanding.

Comment: So I already have the frequency of the people by year, that is the existing count function.  My question is when I have been feeding this into a classification algorithm it seems to be ignoring the counts.  I am trying to get the algorithms to give additional weight to the Count column.

Comment: @Matt you can combine the two columns and make it another feature for your model and use **class_weight** parameter which is inversely proportional to the frequency of so, you can explicitly define the weights of your model.